# Get NodeJS' Nodemailer to send email from a user's address

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I have a contact form on my site which sends the form info to my `NodeJS` api, using `Nodemailer`.

My code looks like this:

```
var mail = {
        from: data.inputName + " <" + data.inputEmail + ">",
        to: 'info@mywebsite.com',
        subject: "Inquiry",
        text: messageText
  }

var smtpTransport = mailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
        service: "Gmail",
        auth: {
            user: "info@mywebsite.com",
            pass: "password12345678"
        }
    });

    smtpTransport.sendMail(mail, function(error, response){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            if(res){
              res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
              res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
              res.send('error');
            }
        }else{
            console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
            if(res){
              console.log("There was res!");
              res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
              res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
              res.send('success');
            }else{
              console.log("There wasn't res!");
            }
        }
        smtpTransport.close();
    });
```

When I receive an email from this, it looks like:

```
from:    User's Inputted Name <info@mywebsite.com> <--- this is bad
to:      info@mywebsite.com <--- this is correct
date:    10 April 2014 18:06
subject: Inquiry
```

How can I get the `from` field to be the user's `data.inputEmail`? I'm assuming it's because I log into the SMTPTransport with my `info@mywebsite.com` username and password, but I have absolutely no idea how to get around this.

Any ideas?

Comment: How is the 'data' object created? maybe there is a mistake somewhere there, or in your form. the node-mail piece seems to be ok.

Comment: @balafi Nope, even if I manually enter an email into the "from" field, it gets sent from the SMTP authenticated email address. Any ideas?